# Error handling in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, exception, try-catch

I have a problem with programming. I want to handle error since it would be work well.
For example in following example i will be increase index to positive value till there is no error anymore :

```
i=-10;
try
result=a[i];
    disp('success');
end
catch
i=i+1;
end
```

It is just simple example to express my problem.
 I will really appreciate, if anyone could help me.

Comment: Don't use try catch for [flow control](http://goo.gl/MQC2xq). Just use `if` statement to check if `i < 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got one superfluous `end` keyword just before the `catch`-line.

It should be

```
result = []
i = -10;
while isempty(result)
   try
      result = a(i);
      disp('success')
   catch
      i = i+1;
   end
end
```

I've also put a loop around it, to make `i` actually be increased.
As an aside, `a[i]` isn't a valid expression in matlab, there is only `a(i)` or `a{i}` (in case a is a cell-array).

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure what you are asking, but I looked up the try/catch page on Matlab and it seems to be helpful. Try/catch helps you deal with errors. For instance, the example they gave about the combinations really highlights its  usage. From what I see you are using try/catch appropriately, provided you have the vector a declared.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I want to change special parameters if error will be happen. Suppose that you set special parameters (in some situation the parameter is not work well and caused error ), For this reason, it will be needed to change parameter.